# Postgres Join two tables with multiple findings in one row

Tags: postgresql

A player can have 1 or 2 teams. I want to join both tables, that every player has only one row with either one or two teams

Given Tables:

```
### Player ###
 id PK
 name 
 team_id

### Team ###
 id PK
 name
```

Values in the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM player;

id | name        | team_id
---+-------------+-------------
1  | John Adams  | 1
2  | John Adams  | 2
3  | Max Roberts | 3


SELECT * FROM team;

id | name
---+------------------
1  | Red Stars
2  | Blue Birds
3  | Grey Tigers
```

I want to join both tables to get the following output of every single player:

```
player_name  | team_1      | team_2
-------------+-------------+------------------
John Adams   | Red Stars   | Blue Birds
Max Roberts  | Grey Tigers | NULL
```

The only thing i can archive so far is the following. But I don't want two rows for John Adams.

```
SELECT player.name as player_name, team.name as team 
FROM player JOIN team ON player.team_id = team.id;

player_name      | team
-----------------+--------------------
John Adams       | Red Stars
John Adams       | Blue Birds
Max Roberts      | Grey Tigers
```

Yeah, i know it isn't a good database layout for the particular scenario, but i cannot change anything to the given db layout.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You just want to show 1 john?

Comment: yeah, but with both team names: player_name, team_1, team_2

Comment: You want to separate if there are player more than 1 team? But the sample just show 2.. How about there are 1 people with 5 team? I think that's not good idea..

Comment: yes, if a player has only one team, team_2 should be NULL. A player can have only two teams. not more.

Comment: Update your question with that condition and add tag sql..

Answer (score 0):

To get your expected output using the current structure you have, you could use [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) with join and group by like

```
select p.name, (array_agg(t.name))[1] team1, (array_agg(t.name))[2] team2
from player p
left join team t on t.id = p.team_id
group by p.name
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/EUY81056)